# Is it possible to send email from PHP application to google group email / distribution list?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer, codeigniter-3, google-groups

I'm able to send emails from my PHP application but when I try to send email to a google's distribution list, ((i.e) a google group) emails are not sent.

I tried both Codeigniter mail and PHPMailer library too.

I get the following diagnostic information for administrators in spam mail:

```
550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipNotFound; not found
```

Answer (score 0):

USE GoogleAPI: authenticate as a Gmail-user who has rights to send to the group and use messages.send() https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending.

Comment: Currently Google API is disabled by administrators so i cannot use that option. Is there any other way using PHP to send it?